# set default value for combo box, if combo box is allowed for multiple values selection

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

if we use a combo box that is allowed to selected multiple values from the list then how can i set a default value for such combo box.

I tried default value property and VB Code

VB Code i used
Me.mycombobox.ListIndex = 0

also tried with

Me.mycombobox = Me.mycombobox.ItemData(0) -- this one works fine for combo box that stores single value.

[image: Here is the image of the combo box]

Comment: Multi-select combobox is bound to a multi-value field. Multi-value fields don't act like normal fields. I NEVER use them.

Comment: There are selected or not selected items. So, if you wish to have some (pre)selected, select these.

Comment: @Gustav so how can i use VBA for pre-selected item. When the form loads the combo box field should have pre-selected items. 
Just like a normal field have a default value when the form loads.
I want this combo box to have some items selected by default when the form loads.

Comment: Loop the items collection and mark those selected which should appear as preselected.